# Subfigure alignment in Beamer

Tags: beamer, subfloats

I have 4 images of same size (350x200 px). I want to use them inside beamer as subfigure of 2x2 matrix. Below is the code-

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Sub-figure Alignment}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.25\textwidth}
            Some content here.\\
            Some content here.\\
            Some content here. 
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img}
                    \caption{Two line long caption}
                    \label{fig:sub1}
                \end{subfigure}\hskip 1em%
                \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img}
                    \caption{One line caption}
                    \label{fig:sub2}
                \end{subfigure}

                \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img}
                    \caption{One line caption}
                    \label{fig:sub1}
                \end{subfigure}\hskip 1em%
                \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img}
                    \caption{Two line long caption}
                    \label{fig:sub2}
                \end{subfigure}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is how generated pdf looks like-
[image]

The caption of each image is different. It is little longer for some of them. I am looking for a way to align the images vertically center, without caring about the caption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the alignment with an option of the subfigure: `\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}`

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,11pt,t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Sub-figure Alignment}
    \begin{columns}[T, onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.25\textwidth}
            Some content here.\\
            Some content here.\\
            Some content here. 
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
                \vskip-\baselineskip
            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \caption{Two line long caption}
                    \label{fig:sub1}
                \end{subfigure}\hskip 1em%
                \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \caption{One line caption}
                    \label{fig:sub2}
                \end{subfigure}

                \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \caption{One line caption}
                    \label{fig:sub1}
                \end{subfigure}\hskip 1em%
                \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
                    \caption{Two line long caption}
                    \label{fig:sub2}
                \end{subfigure}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really easy.. Isn't it? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @RaviJoshi It's only written on the 5th page of the documentation - so not trivial to scroll that far in the pdf :) You're welcome!